# Rule of thumb for interpreting the size of entropy

Tags: entropy, traminer

I have a question regarding the interpretation of entropy. For each person in my dataset, I have a string/sequence of 17 characters(years) long. I am particularly interested in how much variation occurs over this observation period.

I am thinking about using R's TraMineR package to calculate within-sequence entropy for this. I know this can be normalized so the maximum entropy becomes 1 (minimum of 0, obviously). My question is if there is any rule of thumb to say what is high and what is low entropy (e.g. as in the case of correlation coefficients) . For instance, is 0.4 a high or low value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The within-sequence entropy is strongly context dependent. To decide whether the entropy of one specific sequence is high or low, I suggest to compare it with the entropy of other sequences or with the average within-entropy for example.

Likewise, the mean within-sequence entropy of one group, compare it with the mean entropy of the other groups. You could thus conclude for instance something like women have higher occupational entropies than men.